# Prove the convergence of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Given $x_n \sim N(0, \frac{1}{n})$, is $x_n$ **almost sure convergence** or **convergence in probability** or **convergence in distribution**? How to prove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [Borel–Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma), the sequence $X_n\sim N(0,n^{-1})$ converges to $0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$ if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pr\{|X_n|>\varepsilon\}<\infty
$$
for each $\varepsilon>0$. Using [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), we can obtain the following bound
$$
\Pr\{|X_n|>\varepsilon\}\le\frac{\operatorname E|X_n|^4}{\varepsilon^4}.
$$
Since $X_n\sim N(0,n^{-1})$, we know that $\operatorname E|X_n|^4=3(\operatorname E|X_n|^2)^2=3n^{-2}$. We obtain that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Pr\{|X_n|>\varepsilon\}\le\frac3{\varepsilon^4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}<\infty.
$$
Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability and convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: Is the upper bound: $\Pr\{|X_n|>\varepsilon\}\le\frac{\operatorname E|X_n|^2}{\varepsilon^2}$ true? Why do you use the power of 4.

Comment: @useprxf Yes, it is true. If we used this bound, we would obtain $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}=\infty$ since $\operatorname E|X_n|^2=n^{-1}$. So we need a sharper bound.

Comment: Cm7F7Bb, sharper = lower?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, it means lower in this case.